# How to open a specific Activity instead of the LAUNCHER Activity from a Push Notification in Android when using FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm correctly receiving the notifications for my Android app. When the app is in foreground, and I'm receiving and clicking on a notification, it takes me to the right Activity (NewsActivity). But when the app is in background, when I'm clicking a notification, it opens the SplashScreen Activity (which is the Launcher activity) instead of NewsActivity (as I tried in the code). Does anyone know why is this happening? I found different topics on this subject but could not find a solution yet.

**This is the implementation of the FcmMessageListenerService class:**

```
public class FcmMessageListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static final String GENERAL_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "HF_GENERAL_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    if (notification != null) {
        String notificationTitle = notification.getTitle();
        String notificationMessage = notification.getBody();
        displayNotification(notificationTitle, notificationMessage);
    }

}

public void displayNotification(String title, String message) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && notificationManager != null) {
        NotificationChannel generalNotificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(GENERAL_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "General", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        generalNotificationChannel.setDescription("General notifications");
        generalNotificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        generalNotificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        generalNotificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
        generalNotificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        generalNotificationChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(generalNotificationChannel);
    }

    Intent openAppIntent;

    if (SharedPreferencesUtils.getBooleanValue(this, SharedPreferencesUtils.IS_LOGGED_IN_KEY)) {
            openAppIntent = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);
    } else {
        openAppIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    }
    openAppIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            openAppIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    );

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), GENERAL_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    int notificationId = SharedPreferencesUtils.getIntValue(this, SharedPreferencesUtils.NOTIFICATION_UNIQUE_ID_KEY);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
        notificationId++;
        if (notificationId > 100000)
            notificationId = 0;
        SharedPreferencesUtils.setIntValue(this, SharedPreferencesUtils.NOTIFICATION_UNIQUE_ID_KEY, notificationId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NotNull String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);

    SharedPreferencesUtils.removeValueByKey(this, SharedPreferencesUtils.DEVICE_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_TOKEN_KEY);
}
```

**This is the NewsActivity in the Manifest file:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.fragments.news.NewsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|locale|orientation|screenLayout"
        android:label="${appName}"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="locked"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: While creating the PendingIntent use `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`.